# Read value in Excel in Java, problems Windows vs Linux

Tags: java, excel, linux, windows, apache-poi

I have app with Java in Springboot, I read the value numeric from cell **3123456,89**, We are using in Excel the format the money European -> `.` Thousand and `,`  decimals.

```
String stringValue = new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(cell);
```

I read the cell as a String.

Then I parse this String to Double ->

```
Double.parseDouble(stringValue .replaceAll("\\.", "").replaceAll(",", "."));
```

I need this parse because We are insert numerics in format European but Java is format American ( `,` Thousand and `.` decimals)

**This process IS CORRECT WITH WINDOWS.**

Now I upload my app a Linux, I have any problems...

Now I get this value -> `3,123,456,89` , If I use replace -> `"Error multiple points"` If i wish replace `,` I lose part decimal...

I use apache.poi for read the Excels.

```
  <!-- EXCELS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>
```

Finally In linux I have problems with this code, that, in windows is correct. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems your problem results from the fact, that in your `Linux` system `Java` uses a different default `Locale` than in your `Windows` system.

You can construct the `DataFormatter` having a special `Locale`. If that is `Locale.US`, then the whole replacement will not be necessary as the `stringValue` will be formatted for that `Locale.US`. Then you can use `java.text.NumberFormat` of the same locale to get the `Number` out of the string.

```
...
DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter(java.util.Locale.US);
java.text.NumberFormat numberFormat = java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance(java.util.Locale.US);
String stringValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
Double doubleValue = null;
try {
 doubleValue = numberFormat.parse(stringValue).doubleValue();
} catch (Exception ex) {
 //do nothing
}
...
```

Another approach is getting the cell value as numeric value instead of as formatted string.

For `apache poi 3.15` this would be like:

```
...
if (cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
 Double doubleValue = cell.getNumericCellValue();
}
...
```

See also https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will test =)